# What is a "useful" question?

Tags: discussion

When one hovers the cursor over the upvote arrow for an answer, the legend says "This answer is useful". This is a somewhat subjective statement, but for me clear enough: a useful answer is readable and apposite to the question; it settles the question to a fair extent at least; and it goes beyond, or does better than, or at least provides a reasonable alternative to, previous answers. No problem.

Where I have a problem is with the corresponding message for a question: "This question [...] is useful [...]". I am puzzled by what a "useful" question might be. The idea of a "useful question" would no more occur to me than "useful planet" or "useful symphony". I'm not saying that the concept is absurd; it's just that I don't know how to interpret it, and I wonder whether there is general agreement by others as to what it means.

Comment: It is also subjective. If such criteria were objective, then we should have a lot of questions/answers with $N$ upvotes and a lot of questions/answers with $N$ downvotes, where $N$ is the number of users. Thankfully that is not the case.

Comment: [Related question on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70521/262767). There is such a thing as a useful question, and such a thing as a useless question. The famous funny Yahoo question "My dad said something to me but I wasn't listening, what did he say?" is an example of a useless question; you can extrapolate.

Comment: @Najib: That's a very useful question. It tells me "Don't bother with Yahoo! Questions", which is an important piece of knowledge! :-)

Comment: @Jyrki: We should totally have more questions and answers with >100k votes.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I agree that there is such a thing as a useless question, as your example illustrates. Are you saying that a useful question is any question that is not useless? That seems a bit wide to me.

Comment: ...yes, pretty much by definition a question is useful iff it is not useless. $P \iff \neg\neg P$ (take that intuitionists).

Comment: I am somewhat surprised by the number of downvotes on this question. I think it is useful to have some discussion about this. For me, not for the sake of voting. (I have my own criteria by which I decide whether to upvote or downvote.) But whether a question is useful also comes into decisions whether some questions should be closed or deleted.

Comment: @MartinSleziak the style of the question feels a bit polemic to me or at least exaggerated. Let us focus on a detail: OP has problems with the notion of a "useful question" and evokes "useful planet" or "useful symphony" as analogy. Then, in the comments, it transpires OP has no problems with the notion  "useless question." Idly I wonder what OP considers as a  "useless symphony." Or maybe it is just  the analogy was not so good to begin with.

Comment: @quid: The fact that one may understand someone's description of a particular question as useless does not imply that one has a concept of what a useful question is. In particular, I would not deem a question to be useful just because I couldn't call it useless. I am sorry if the tone of my question comes across as polemic or exaggerated. The "useful question" has niggled me slightly for years, so perhaps there is too much accumulation of niggle in my posting. (Incidentally, I have no idea what either a useful or a useless symphony is.)

Comment: It is still not quite clear to me what your issue with "useful question" is. The idea to judge if knowing some particular mathematical fact should be more or less  *useful* does not strike me as unusual. In varied ways this is what being a mathematician is mainly about. If the question asks, in a clear way, about something that I deem useful, then it seems natural to qualify it as useful. If not, then not.

Comment: @quid: Most of the questions on this site seek help with students' homework. If such a question is intelligible and able to elicit an appropriate answer (as most are), then presumably it is "useful" to the asker. In that rather trivial sense, most questions are useful. On the other hand, most visitors to the site would find the majority of questions of no interest, and so not useful to them personally. Either interpretation of *useful* seems too broad and trivial to be worth stating as a criterion; so I gather that some (unknown) more significant and perhaps more objective sense is intended.

Comment: I already gave you another sense, which you chose to dismiss by pretending it were not  actionable. Beyond that the full hover text is something like: this questions shows research effort; it is useful  and clear. So one would then be encouraged to upvote all homework question that show effort, are clear and not useless. In what precise way is this unreasonable? Further, the point of the useful there  is  to put a certain focus on question that are actually useful to somebody, as opposed to being some form of challenge, a made up puzzle, or some curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

This site is a collection of a certain type of questions (with their respective answers). Given this context, a question is useful if it is a useful addition to this collection of questions.

What this means specifically will depend on ones conception of the scope and the goals of the site; but irrespective of those details I believe the definition given above makes sense.

Comment: "This collection of questions" is such a diverse assemblage of material, ranging from the trivial to the profound, most of which I have never even glimpsed, that I have no conception of it as a single entity, let alone what might be a "useful" addition to it.

Comment: If you do not feel competent to vote, just do not vote.

Comment: That's good advice, which I follow anyway for questions on topics where I have no competence. Otherwise, I do vote, although not according to whether I consider the question "useful" (which, as I explained above, has uncertain meaning for me).